# Updating approval status of a item | On Save | Event System

Tags: event-system, 2013-sp1-hr1

So when we save a Component, by default a major version is created with the "undefined" approval status. And with this approval status this Component can be published to any Publication Target irrespective of you set a minimum approval status for the Publication Target.

We want to stop this behavior, and assign a custom approval status when a Component is saved using Event System. We can update the approval status to "Unapproved" (out of the box) status using the below code on the Save Event of a Component, but not to a Custom Approval Status defined in Tridion.

```
 private void OnSave(VersionedItem subject, SaveEventArgs e, EventPhases phase)
    { 
 IWorkflowItem item = null;
 if (subject is Component)
            {

                item = subject as Component;
            }
    if (item.ApprovalStatus != null && !item.ApprovalStatus.Title.Equals("undefined", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                    {

                        e.ApprovalStatusResetOverride = ApprovalStatusType.Unapproved;

                    }
    }
```

Question:
Is there a way to assign a custom (Tridion defined) approval status, while saving a Component using Event System?
(I don't want to start a workflow to update the approval status from Event System)

Answer (score 6):

Approval status is currently a read only property in the API and the only way it can be changed is via a workflow process (other than what you've currently done with your event system, which is limited to the built-in types of Undefined or Unapproved).

For one customer with a requirement similar to yours, I have implemented a simple, automated workflow which just assigns items a draft status and ends. It's not ideal (IMHO) and I'm not sure I'd recommend it to other customers but it does work.

I actually *prefer* your Event System, which does not require a workflow process to run and I would consider it as an *enhancement* for the customer I mention above, as an Unapproved status would work for them. Is there a reason that you really need a custom status?

Comment: Well, the "Unapproved" status causes the publishing to fail on all the publishing targets. Now for live publishing target, it serve the purpose and meet the requirement but this becomes a issue for staging publishing target. To approve some content for Live, user needs to see the content on staging first and for this we must run the content through a workflow, which gives the content "Staging" minimum approval status. And we don't want a separate workflow for staging.

Comment: Hmm... OK. Do you need a minimum approval status set on your staging target? I don't normally see that - usually I see them set to have no minimum status at all.

Comment: Even if you don't have a minimum approval status for staging, "Unapproved" content will fail. Right?

Comment: No, I just double checked this because I didn't realise at first that you had one set for your staging target. Unapproved components can be published to a target with no minimum approval status.

Comment: Hmmm... Thanks for the info David